# Windows 8 and cell modem com port information

Tags: c#, windows, wmi

We have a device that uses a Sierra MC7354 modem running on a windows 8 embedded device.  The issue I'm having is that the device manager will show the com port for the modem but code that works on our embedded XP systems and my development laptop running windows 7 does not work on the our build of 8 embedded.

We currently are using WMI to search for the modem.  The namespace used for the WMI query is "root\CimV2" and the ClassName is "Win32_POTSModem".  When we use a ClassName of "Win32_NetworkAdaptor" we do see the modem.  We also see 2 of the three comports when searching for "Win32_PnPEntity", just not the com port we need to send "AT" commands to the modem.  Our software has been ran from a admin CMD window that should avoid permission issues.

The desired comport is listed in SerialPort.GetPortNames.  We are un-able to send AT commands to each port to find the modem that way due to other serial hardware that would be negatively impacted by sending the query.

Here is a simple test app, windows 8 embedded returns 0 modems and 15 network adapters where my laptop returns 15 modems and 43 network adapters:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Management;

namespace wmiModemTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Modem();
            Network();
        }
        static void Modem()
        {
            //create a management scope object
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\ROOT\\cimv2");

            //create object query
            ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_POTSModem");

            //create object searcher
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                                    new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

            //get a collection of WMI objects
            ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();

            Console.WriteLine("Number of Win32_POTSModem returned: {0}", queryCollection.Count);
            //enumerate the collection.
            foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
            {
                // access properties of the WMI object
                Console.WriteLine("Description : {0}", m["Description"]);

            }
        }
        static void Network()
        {
            //create a management scope object
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope("\\\\.\\ROOT\\cimv2");

            //create object query
            ObjectQuery query = new ObjectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter");

            //create object searcher
            ManagementObjectSearcher searcher =
                                    new ManagementObjectSearcher(scope, query);

            //get a collection of WMI objects
            ManagementObjectCollection queryCollection = searcher.Get();

            Console.WriteLine("Number of Win32_NetworkAdapter returned: {0}", queryCollection.Count);
            //enumerate the collection.
            foreach (ManagementObject m in queryCollection)
            {
                // access properties of the WMI object
                Console.WriteLine("Description : {0}", m["Description"]);

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how the WMI info for modems is gathered or how the device manager gets the information?